# Tensor contraction and associativity

Tags: tensor-products, associativity

I'm a tensor newbie and while solving some problems in a book, I generated the following double contraction:
$$
\delta^i_{k} \delta^{k}_{i} = 3
$$
Multiplying both sides by $\delta^{m}_{i}$ gives me
$$
\delta^{m}_{i} \delta^{i}_{k} \delta^{k}_{i} = 3 \delta^{m}_{i}
$$
Index renaming yields
$$
\delta^{m}_{k} \delta^{k}_{i} = 3 \delta^{m}_{i}
$$
$$
\delta^{m}_{i} = 3 \delta^{m}_{i}
$$
Which, kinda seems like nonsense.  What rule did I break or what misrepresentation did I make?

thanks

Comment: "Multiplying both sides by $\delta^m_i$" is illegal. In Einstein notation, if the same index appears more than twice, then the said index is not summed.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Einstein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) notation the first of your equations should be understood as the result of

$$
\delta_k^i\delta_i^k \equiv \sum_i\sum_k \delta_k^i\delta_i^k = \sum_i\delta_i^i = 3
$$

The problem with your second equation is that you have the index $i$ repeated *three* times which does not make sense in this notation

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Is it an odd number that fails or any number > 2?  The actual problem came up in a proof that the contravariant metric is a tensor starting from the identity. $g_{im}g^{mj}=\delta^i_j$ where I know that the covariant metric is a tensor.  Throw in some Jacobians  and you end up with multiple instances of indices.

Comment: @MarcoDallaGasperina Any number beyond 2, the notation applies for an upper index and the same symbol for a lower index

Answer (score 0):

The summation convention *really* insists on repeated indices occurring only twice! Your paradox illustrates why: When you multiply $\delta^i_k\delta^k_i$ by $\delta^m_i$, you are really multiplying
$\sum_{i,k}\delta^i_k\delta^k_i$
by $\delta^m_i$. The answer is *not* $\sum_{i,k}\delta^i_k\delta^k_i\delta^m_i$!
You would have to rename the summation index $i$ to $j$ first:
Then you multiply $\sum_{i,k}\delta^i_k\delta^k_i=\sum_{j,k}\delta^j_k\delta^k_j$ by $\delta^m_i$, and you get the result $\sum_{j,k}\delta^j_k\delta^k_j\delta^m_i$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs in the second line. You're already summing over $i$ and $k$. Try replacing $\delta_i^m$ with a different index, say $\delta_j^
m$.